# Get textbox.Text from FORM to CLASS

Tags: c#, winforms, class

I have tried to get the textbox.text to a class and it doesent work what am I am doing wrong please help!

In my form.cs it looks like this:

```
    public string score1;
    public void getPlayerOneScore1Input()
    {
        score1 = playerOneScore1TextBox.Text;
    }


    public void playerOneAddScoreButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        score1Calculator theCalculator = new score1Calculator(score1);


    }
```

and in my CLASS it looks like this:

```
    class score1Calculator
    {
    public score1Calculator(string score1)
        {
            this.score1= score1;

        }

    public int playerOneDart1Value;
    public void calculateDart1()
    {
        if (score1== "t1" || score1== "T1" || score1== "3")
        {
            playerOneDart1Value = 3;

        }
  else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Dart 1! This is not a valid input!");
            return;


        }
        }


       }
```

error i get: 
'WindowsFormApplication1.score1Calculator' does not contain a definition for 'player' and no extension method 'player' accepting a first argument of type 'WindowsFormApplication1.score1Calculator' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: please post your dart1Calculator code - your score1Calculator isn't complete either.

Comment: And in which line does this error occur? It seems like you called a method `player` which you did not actually implement. The error will show you where.

Comment: on this.score1=score1 @Marwie

Comment: @MartinNielsen You have not defined any global `score1' variable in the class, `score1Calculator`. You should be getting a compile time error.

Comment: @P.K. How do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to do it overly complicated. A `Textbox.Text` value is just a string. You can directly call the constructor with this reference.

Just write it like this

```
score1Calculator theCalculator = new dart1Calculator(playerOneScore1TextBox.Text);
```

No need to store the value on module level.

Comment: Thanks, but still get the same error, how would you catch it in the class? @Marwie

Comment: @MartinNielsen add your error to your question please, so that we can comment on it.

Answer (score 0):

you dont call `getPlayerOneScore1Input()` in order the `score1` to be assigned, in Form1 try:

```
 public void playerOneAddScoreButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getPlayerOneScore1Input();
        score1Calculator theCalculator = new dart1Calculator(score1);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but still get the same error, how would you catch it in the class? @apomene

Answer (score 0):

On button click you are not calling your function `getPlayerOneScore1Input()` which actually assign value to `score1`.

```
public void playerOneAddScoreButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    getPlayerOneScore1Input();
    score1Calculator theCalculator = new dart1Calculator(score1);
}
```

Instead of assigning value to `score1` in form class and assign it to your class member field. You may try this.

```
public void playerOneAddScoreButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(playerOneScore1TextBox.Text))
    {
         score1Calculator theCalculator = new dart1Calculator(playerOneScore1TextBox.Text);
    }
}
```